# How can I send a message to every server the bot is in with python discord

Tags: python, discord.py

I would like it so that when I type a command and a message it will forward that message to a channel in every server the bot is connected to with python discord. I know how to get the message and look for the command but I do not know how to find a channel the bot can post in, in every server and then send it.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through all the servers the bot can see, then loop through their channels until you find one you can send messages to.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def broadcast(ctx, *, msg):
    for server in bot.servers:
        for channel in server.channels:
            try:
                await bot.send_message(channel, msg)
            except Exception:
                continue
            else:
                break
```

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE to patrick's code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def broadcast(ctx, *, msg):
    for server in bot.guilds:
        for channel in server.text_channels:
            try:
                await channel.send(msg)
            except Exception:
                continue
            else:
                break
```

Changes: Servers Are Now Called Guilds, we need to use the send method of channel class , also we want to use only text_channels.

Comment: How would this be modified to not send to rules?

Answer (score 0):

The `servers` object of your `Client` is an iterable of `Server` objects the bot is part of, and each `Server` contains a `channels` iterable you can use to get the channels you can post in.

```
client = discord.Client()
await client.wait_until_ready()
channels = []
for server in client.servers:
  for channel in server.channels:
     channels.append(channel)
     # If you have your discord.Message object (message) and
     # command you want to send (command_str) you could then:
     # await client.send_message(message.channel, command_str)
# channels will now be populated with all the possible channels
```

[Docs on client servers](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.servers)

[Docs on server channels](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Server.channels)

[Docs on client messaging](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.send_message)